# Can't import meteor packages when using typescript

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript

I'm trying to create a simple test in Meteor with Typescript, using `meteortypescript:compiler` and `practicalmeteor:mocha`. When my file is named `Foo_test.js` the code below works fine. When I name it `Foo_test.ts`, I get errors:

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Random} from 'meteor/random';

// With typescript, the line below gives:
// Cannot find module 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai'
// Without typescript, there are no errors
import { assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
```

Why am I seeing the error when using Typescript, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you have typings files for `meteor/practicalmeteor:chai` package? If not, `tsc` is just complaining because it doesn't know the package.

Comment: I installed typings for meteor, mocha, and chai from DefinitelyTyped. Do I need additional typings?